# Jquery Timing Plugin Usage

Tags: jquery

So I have been looking for a resolve to the issue, and Hopefully one of the smart guys here can help...

I have a $.each function that runs and loops through a couple hundred selects, check's if it needs to post to a URL and if it does, post's for the update to happen.
The problem I have is with the $.each function, it just bombards the server with requests...
The second problem is, that I can't accurately time it, so either I am too fast, or too slow and it ruins the experience/performance...

So I found a plugin for jquery which helps you queue it: http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing

The only problem is, the documents don't make sense. I can set it out for a period of let's say 1 second between each loop easily, but I still don't know the time...
The do reference a wait for event but I don't understand how it works.

Can someone help me convert the code below, So that the wait command will wait for the jquery POST response to happen before continuing?

**Code:**

```
$( "#SubmitTransactionSync" ).click(function() {
        $( "#SubmitTransactionSync" ).attr("disabled", true);
        var length = $( ".TransactionSelects" ).length-1;
        $( ".TransactionSelects" ).each($).wait(1000, function(index) {
            $( "#SubmitTransactionSync" ).text('Processing Item '+index+'/'+length);
            if($(this).val()!='skip'){
                var data = { 
                    token: '',
                    SyncTransactions: true
                };
                data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
                $.post( 
                    "?action=ProcessSyncTransactions", 
                    data, 
                    function( response ) {
                        console.log( response );
                    }, 
                    "json"
                );
            }

            if(index==length){
                $( "#SubmitTransactionSync" ).text('Completing Process');
                setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); }, 1500);
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: May i ask why are you sending data from one select at a time? why not send all values in one go?

Comment: @NawedKhan the amount of data that needs to be processed is A LOT and since the receiving server can only accept 100 requests per minute before it blocks us, I am sitting with a time out issue. All alternatives are making the process unstable or take TOO long. This way I am using php to check if it can send and delay if not, but it's a 1s delay, not a 30-60 second delay in a single php script (Which would cause a timeout)